# How to join the same table in sql?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to have table A's cateogry column join in the table B.  How to write the join in same table?

Here is the sql script for table A

```
select code_id, code_desc category
FROM t_setup_code 
WHERE code_id IN (select code_1 from t_setup_code WHERE code_desc LIKE 'Ag%');
```

Here is the sql script for table B

```
SELECT a.plot_sub_usage, b.code_id, b.code_1, b.code_desc, COUNT(*)
FROM dc_plot a, t_setup_code b
WHERE a.plot_sub_usage = b.code_id
AND b.code_id LIKE 'LUC-AG%'
GROUP BY a.plot_sub_usage, b.code_desc, b.code_id, b.code_1
ORDER BY a.plot_sub_usage;
```

Here is the results for both sql scripts

[image]

Result should look like this:
[image]

Comment: whats the expected output

Comment: Hi Gaj,  I amend my posting with the result from outcome should look like.  Hardly type in text in the reply comment.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, please see my question is provided with code not in image only. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT a.plot_sub_usage, b.code_desc, c.code_desc, COUNT(*)
FROM dc_plot a 
        inner join t_setup_code b on a.plot_sub_usage = b.code_id
        inner join t_setup_code c on c.code_id = b.code_1
WHERE b.code_id LIKE 'LUC-AG%'
AND c.code_desc like 'Ag%'
GROUP BY a.plot_sub_usage, b.code_desc, c.code_desc
ORDER BY a.plot_sub_usage;
```